# $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\text{e}^h -1}{h}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, exponential-function

I want to show that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\text{e}^h -1}{h}=1$$

by using the Squeeze theorem. Is it possible to prove this with the Squeeze theorem?

Maybe the two inequalities

$$ \forall \, h \in (-1,1) \colon 1+h \leq \text{e}^h \leq \frac{1}{1-h} $$
$$ \forall \, h > 0 \colon 1 \leq \frac{\text{e}^h-1}{h} \leq \frac{1}{1-h}$$

are helpful. The second inequality looks already good, but the problem is that it holds only for $h > 0$.

Comment: Do you necessarily have to do this using the squeeze theorem?

Comment: As usual with foundational problems involving $e$, this comes down to what you're allowed to use. Some people *define* $e$ as the unique positive real number which has this property, after having carefully defined exponentiation with irrational numbers. Others define $e$ by defining $e^x$ through its derivative. Still others use the "continuous compound interest" definition $e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right )^n$. Defining $e$ by derivatives again defines the answer; defining through the "compound interest" definition makes this problem a bit difficult.

Comment: It is for my own purpose and I want to show this by using the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: Euler's number is defined by $\text{e} : = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ and 



$$ \text{exp} \colon \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow (0,\infty) \colon x \longmapsto \text{e}^x := \text{exp}(x) :=\sup \left\lbrace \text{e}^q, q \in \mathbb{Q} \ \text{with} \ q \leq x\right\rbrace.$$

Comment: Of course, for your information, this is just the derivative of the exponential function at $x_0=0$. That is why I asked if you necessarily have to do this using the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here goes:

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such as $n>-x$. Hence $\dfrac{x}{n}+1>0$, so $\displaystyle \left ( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right )^n\geq 1+n \cdot \frac{x}{n}=1+x$. (from Bernoulli's inequality)

Therefore:
$$e^x=\lim \left ( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right )^n \geq \lim (1+x) =1+x \implies e^x \geq 1+x$$

Subbing in the previous equation whereas $x$ the $-x$ we get: $e^{-x}\geq 1-x$ and forall $x \in (-1, 1)$ we have $\displaystyle e^x\leq \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Thus we get:
$$1+x\leq e^x\leq \frac{1}{1-x} \implies x\leq e^x-1\leq \frac{x}{x-1}$$
(which is what you've got).Now divide by $x$

If $0<x<1$ then the inequality remains as it is, otherwise if $-1<x<0$ the inequality is reversed. In both cases using the squeeze theorem you get what you want.

Comment: I thought for using the Squeeze theorem I need the same functions on both sides and the inequality must hold for a small interval around $0$.

Comment: But [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) it says so.

Comment: No, the squeeze theorem states that:

Let $f,g, h$ be real valued function of a real variable such that:

a)$g(x)\leq f(x) \leq h(x) $ on an interval $\mathcal{A}$
b)$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0} h(x)=\ell \in \mathbb{R}$

then the limit of $f$ at $x_0$ is $\ell$.

Comment: Yes but we are changing the functions $f$ and $g$ when we divde by the negative $x$.

Comment: No, we are not changing the functions. We are reversing the inequality.

Comment: The problem is that the inequailty $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ does not hold on the interval $[-1,1]$ in our case. That was actually my question.

Comment: Look more carefully , what I've written. I have written that on $(-1, 1)$ this inequality holds. That $\mathcal{A}=(-1, 1)$.

Comment: No, I think you are wrong. We have $g(x)=1$, $f(x)= \frac{\text{e}^x -1}{x}$ and $h(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$. But the inequality $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ is wrong for $x \in (-1,1)$.

Comment: No, the inequality holds! Both of them are quite known. Because when you divide by a negative number it reverses....

Comment: $g(x) \leq f(x)$ is wrong for $x \in (-1,0)$. We already had this discussion.

Comment: Probably you did not understand.. At the end of my answer I say that if $x \in (-1, 0)$ the inequality reverses....

Comment: I know that the inequality reverses. But for the Squeeze theorem we need two fixed functions $g$ and $h$ and the inequality $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ must hold for an interval including the point $0$. I think you are wrong. What are your functions $g$ and $h$ which fulfill $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ for $x \in (-1,1)?$.

Comment: This is actually wrong. For the Squeeze theorem you need different functions.

Comment: @user345322 On the one hand, you can split the squeezing, consider the left-hand limit and the right-hand limit separately. The limit exists if and only if both one-sided limits exist and are equal. On the other hand, you can take $g(x) = \min \left\{1, \frac{1}{1-x}\right\}$ and $h(x) = \max \left\{ 1, \frac{1}{1-x}\right\}$.